# Azure VM (Not Classic) - Cannot deploy website using Web Deploy from VS 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, virtual-machine, web-deployment

I'm getting a time out error in VS Publish Web module when trying to validate my http connection to our Azure VM. I'm simply looking for a better way for our small dev team to deploy our MVC website to the VM other than publishing to file or publishing to FTP.

- I've got Web Deploy on our Windows 2016 server, and the proper
  services are running.
- Remote Service is installed with Web Deploy.
- Port 8172 is open and I am able to connect using Telnet from my
  remote box.
- I updated the pubxml file with:

  `<AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
  <UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>
  <UserName>un</UserName>
  <Password>pw</Password>`

Not sure what else to try at this point, but this has been a PITA to say the least. Thanks for any input! FYI - This is not Azure Classic.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buKq4.png)

Comment: Could you telnet 8172 on your Visual-studio PC? According to the error log, it seems that that port is not open on server side. You need open port 8172 on Windows Firewall and Azure NSG(Inbound).

Comment: The port is opened and I tested successfully from my remote VS PC using telnet. I did add a new inbound rule for port 8172 in the NSG as well with no success. I know it's reaching the server because if I put in the wrong credentials, I get a credential error versus a timeout.

Comment: Yes, if your credential is wrong, you will get password wrong not timeout. Do you open port on Windows Firewall?

Comment: Firewall is off ATM. The OS is Windows Server 2016. I've also rebooted the server several times as well as my VS PC.

Comment: I suggest you had better check as the [link](http://azureblogger.com/2016/02/enabling-web-deploy-from-visual-studio-to-an-azure-virtual-machine/). Now, you have open port on Azure NSG, you had better check your IIS configuration on your VM.

Comment: Check from step3, classic and ARM VM for your scenario is only different from open port on endpoint(classic VM) and NSG(ARM VM).